# MySQL Months stored as strings, how to order chronologically, rather than alphabetically?

Tags: mysql

I've got months stored in a table like this "December, August, July", etc. How can I order my query so that they're ordered chronologically rather than alphabetically? I probably need to convert from string to time to get a number then order by that, I can do this in PHP but don't know how to do this directly within the query so I don't have to make a query, use PHP to manipulate some data, then make another query using that.

Can MySQL do this in a query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will hate this :-

```
order by 
case month_column
  when "January" then 1
  when "February" then 2
  ...
  when "December" then 12
end case
```

There is another [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function in mysql

```
mysql> select str_to_date('January', '%M');
+------------------------------+
| str_to_date('January', '%M') |
+------------------------------+
| 0000-01-00                   |
+------------------------------+

--> sorting
order by str_to_date(column_name, '%M')
```

Since you not going to provide other information (year,day, time),
so this function will work too.

The best way is convert all the string into small integer,
which is the correct way and have the best optimization

Comment: You were right, I do hate that case based solution. But this isn't an ideally planned database at all, anyway. I used your order by str_to_date solution which works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: How to do same if we have month and year as different field?

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is create another table

```
CREATE TABLE MONTH_NAME
( 
    MONTH_NAME VARCHAR, // or whatever type the month is in your db
    MONTH_NUMBER INT
)
```

Fill with "January", 1 etc

Then in the query join the two tables here in on the month name and order by the MONTH_NUMBER.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html):

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN `month` = 'January' THEN 1
    WHEN `month` = 'February' THEN 2
    WHEN `month` = 'March' THEN 3
    WHEN `month` = 'April' THEN 4
    WHEN `month` = 'May' THEN 5
    ....
END AS orderbymonth
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY orderbymonth ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `months` table, then you can order by `month_number`.

```
select field from tablename join months using (month_name) 
  order by month_number asc;
```

e.g.

```
insert into months (month_name, month_number) 
  values ('January', 1), ('February', 2), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column in the table db type integer. Then i would create another reference table with the monthes Col1 Name:January Col2 Value:1:Col1 Name:February Col2 Value:2 .. etc
Then i would inner join with the names, and order by the value. Works 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY FIELD(month_column,
'December', 'November', 'October',
'September', 'August', 'July',
'June', 'May', 'April',
'March', 'February', 'January') DESC, month_column ASC
```

Hope this would help.